# Compare output rather than command

Tags: bash, string-comparison

Trying to create a script to read a remote file and check the md5 checksum and alert if a mismatch yet getting an error I can't understand.

```
#!/bin/sh
REMOTEMD5=$(ssh user@host 'md5sum file.txt')
LOCALMD5=$(md5sum 'file.txt')
if [$LOCALMD5 !== $REMOTEMD5]
then
  echo "all OK"
else
  echo -e "no match, Local:"$LOCALMD5"\nRemote:"$REMOTEMD5
fi
```

This returns  `line 4: [6135222a12f06b2dfce6a5c1b736891e: command not found`

I've tried using ' or " around the $LOCALMD5 but never seem able to get this to compare the outputs. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try;

```
if [ "$LOCALMD5" == "$REMOTEMD5" ]
```

which should work better.

Edit: I think you got == and != reversed in your code.

Comment: Thanks for trying however this still returns command not found

Comment: Strange, works fine for me when I run it. What is the specific error message now?

Comment: Well spotted, I've tried this so many ways around today my eyes were telling me lies. Now works correctly

Comment: @moztech Also, try to use `[[` instead of `[`. Read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) .. it's good stuff :)

Comment: You MUST have spaces after [ and before ]. The hint is in the error message which starts with [

Comment: I believe this example should be one `=` sign.  See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html.  With `==` it, I get "unexpected operator" results some of the time, depending on whether they equal or not.

Answer (score 10):

I think it should be like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
REMOTEMD5=$(ssh user@host 'md5sum file.txt')
LOCALMD5=$(md5sum 'file.txt')
if [ "$LOCALMD5" == "$REMOTEMD5" ]
then
  echo "all OK"
else
  echo -e "no match, Local:"$LOCALMD5"\nRemote:"$REMOTEMD5
fi
```

The space between the bracket and the value is important!

Comment: Very close, I'm now getting
`no match, Local: 6135222a12f06b2dfce6a5c1b736891e file.txt
Remote: 6135222a12f06b2dfce6a5c1b736891e file.txt`

Comment: The values are identical -> your condition says if the values are unequal the script should print ok ...., seems fine to me!

Comment: Thanks, as noted by @JoachimIsaksson I had got my logic reversed from an earlier attempt as well as some bad code

Comment: As already mentioned in the comments, that `!=` needs to be `==`. I'd edit the answer myself, but StackOverflow requires me to make at least 6 characters worth of changes.

Answer (score 7):

`[` isn't bash syntax, it is a command. So you must have a space between it and its first argument `$LOCALMD5`. There also needs to be a space between `$REMOTEMD5` and `]`.